# Reading chunks of csv file in Python using pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a question concerning reading bits and pieces of a csv file. When just reading the file using

```
pd.read_csv(path,sep=';',na_values=[''],thousands='.',decimal=',',date_parser=[0])
```

I get:

```
     EUR     1Y     2Y     3Y
0  2013-09-25  0,198  0,307  0,485
1  2013-09-26  0,204  0,318  0,497
2  2013-09-27  0,204  0,306  0,487
3  2013-09-28  0,204  0,306  0,487
4         USD     1Y     2Y     3Y
5  2013-09-25  0,462  0,571  0,749
6  2013-09-26  0,468  0,582  0,761
7  2013-09-27  0,468   0,57  0,751
8  2013-09-28  0,468   0,57  0,751
```

As you can see, the data is arranged date-wise, and each data set is in chunks after one another (in this case the USD-data comes straight after the EUR-data). The currency-label tricks up things a bit, and the data becomes one single data frame.

What I would like to have are two separate data frames, as

```
     EUR     1Y     2Y     3Y
0  2013-09-25  0,198  0,307  0,485
1  2013-09-26  0,204  0,318  0,497
2  2013-09-27  0,204  0,306  0,487
3  2013-09-28  0,204  0,306  0,487

     USD     1Y     2Y     3Y
0  2013-09-25  0,462  0,571  0,749
1  2013-09-26  0,468  0,582  0,761
2  2013-09-27  0,468   0,57  0,751
3  2013-09-28  0,468   0,57  0,751
```

That is, I would like to separate each currency data set from one another.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an alternative approach to the problem. It reads the csv into a single DataFrame and then uses a bit of data-wrangling to create a currency column:

```
           currency     1Y     2Y     3Y
date                                    
2013-09-25      EUR  0,198  0,307  0,485
2013-09-26      EUR  0,204  0,318  0,497
2013-09-27      EUR  0,204  0,306  0,487
2013-09-28      EUR  0,204  0,306  0,487
2013-09-25      USD  0,462  0,571  0,749
2013-09-26      USD  0,468  0,582  0,761
2013-09-27      USD  0,468   0,57  0,751
2013-09-28      USD  0,468   0,57  0,751
```

You could then "split" the DataFrame into smaller DataFrames according to the currency using `groupby`:

```
groups = df.groupby(['currency'])
for key, grp in groups:
    print(grp)
```

---

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_table('data',sep=';',na_values=[''],thousands='.',decimal=',',
                   names=['date', '1Y', '2Y', '3Y'])
mask = df['date'].str.contains('^\s*\D')              # 1
df['currency'] = (df['date']
                  .where(mask, np.nan)                # 2
                  .fillna(method='ffill'))            # 3
df = df.loc[~mask]                                    # 4

print(df)    

groups = df.groupby(['currency'])
for key, grp in groups:
    print(grp)
```

---

1. Use `str.contains` to find values in `df['date']` which begin with a non-digit. The values are presumed to be currencies. The `mask` is `True` on these rows.

   ```
   In [120]: mask
   Out[120]: 
   0     True
   1    False
   2    False
   3    False
   4    False
   5     True
   6    False
   7    False
   8    False
   9    False
   Name: date, dtype: bool
   ```
2. `df['date'].where(mask, np.nan)` returns a Series, equal to
   `df['date']` where the mask is `True`, and `np.nan` otherwise.
3. Forward-fill in the `nans` with the currency values

   ```
   In [123]: df['date'].where(mask, np.nan).fillna(method='ffill')
   Out[123]: 
   0    EUR
   1    EUR
   2    EUR
   3    EUR
   4    EUR
   5    USD
   6    USD
   7    USD
   8    USD
   9    USD
   Name: date, dtype: object
   ```
4. Select only those rows where the mask is `False`, thus removing the header rows.

Comment: Really nice solution as well. Actually more inline to what I need, as I will eventually need to transfer everything into an Excel Pivot-table (so the currency column makes things a lot things easier). @unutbu
However, I can't seem to get the line
mask = data['date'].str.match('^\s*\D')
to work... i only get () and [] as output for 'mask'...

Comment: Solved it by using mask = data['date'].str.CONTAINS('^\s*\D') instead of MATCH. Thanks again @unutbu

Answer (score 1):

Use the `nrows` and `skiprows` parameter to [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html)

So for first dataframe read just the first 4 rows:

```
eur = pd.read_csv(path,sep=';',na_values=[''],thousands='.',decimal=',',date_parser=[0], nrows=4)
```

and subsequent dataframe skip first 5 rows:

```
usd = pd.read_csv(path,sep=';',na_values=[''],thousands='.',decimal=',',date_parser=[0], skiprows=5)
```

should work

Comment: Very nice solution! @EdChum. You don't happen to know a quick fix to automate the nrows, skiprows? e.g. "find first occurence of non-date -> start from there"?

Comment: You would have to read the csv iteratively and detect when you didn't receive a date string unfortunately, there is no built in method for pandas. You could pass the `dtype` param to explicitly tell pandas what the dtypes are the columnsn, it should fail and then note when the error occurs.

Comment: The other possibility is to slice the incorrect dataframe to yield 2 correct dataframes e.g `eur = df.iloc[0:4] usd = df.iloc[5:10]` for example, you would have to rename the column for the usd df though